# Check if boolean is true?

Tags: c#

```
bool foo = true;

// Do this?
if (foo)
{
}

// Or this?
if (foo == true)
{
}
```

I like one of them and my coworker the other. The result is the same, but what is (more) correct?

Comment: It's a matter of style.  I doubt you'll get a definitive answer on this one.

Comment: I wish I could vote to close as general duplicate. There are waaaaaaay too many questions on this and they are all equally subjective.

Comment: Jon Skeet likes the first one. Thus, it is the correct way...end of discussion! ;-)

Comment: A definite answer is not necessary. Just wanted a discussion about it :)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Almost everyone I've seen expressing an opinion prefers

```
if (foo)
{
}
```

Indeed, I've seen many people criticize the explicit comparison, and I may even have done so myself before now. I'd say the "short" style is idiomatic.

EDIT:

Note that this doesn't mean that line of code is always incorrect. Consider:

```
bool? maybeFoo = GetSomeNullableBooleanValue();
if (maybeFoo == true)
{
    ...
}
```

That will compile, but without the "== true" it won't, as there's no implicit conversion from `bool?` to `bool`.

Comment: Agreed. The only time I'd use the verbose (foo == true) is if the foo variable name is not obviously a boolean, just for readability.

Comment: +1 for the `bool?` comment. I have been using `(maybeFoo.HasValue && maybeFoo.Value)` but `maybeFoo == true` is much nicer.

Comment: @fredw: Another option is to add the "default" value: `if (maybeFoo ?? false)` or `if (maybeFoo ?? true)`. But I prefer the `==` in general.

Comment: Now you can do `if (maybeFoo is true)`

Answer (score 27):

It depends on your situation.

I would say, if your bool has a good name, then:

```
if (control.IsEnabled)  // Read "If control is enabled."
{
}
```

would be preferred.

If, however, the variable has a not-so-obvious name, checking against `true` would be helpful in understanding the logic.

```
if (first == true)  // Read "If first is true."
{
}
```

Comment: +1 readability should guide the answer - ideally you would rename the variable so you can use the former.

Comment: If the name isn't obvious, perhaps it should be renamed...

Comment: When dealing with embedded systems, often you need to check the status of a single bit.  In C# it is perfectly reasonable to store the bit as a boolean.  In which case, checking if the boolean is true can provide more legibility than renaming the variable.  For example, consider a bit which indicates whether data should be an input or output.  You could name the variable `IsOutputBit`, but it is perhaps more legible to name as `IODirection`.  I admit, it may be even better to create a 2 value enum for these purposes.

Answer (score 23):

If you're going to opt for

```
if(foo == true)
```

why not go all the way and do

```
if(foo == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true == true)
```

Which is the same thing.

I disagree that if its clearly named (ie: `IsSomething`) then its ok to not compare to true, but otherwise you should.  If its in an if statement obviously it can be compared to true.

```
if(monday)
```

Is just as descriptive as

```
if(monday == true)
```

I also prefer the same standard for not:

```
if(!monday)
```

as opposed to

```
if(monday == false)
```

Answer (score 4):

The first example nearly always wins in my book:

```
if(foo)
{
}
```

It's shorter and more concise. Why add an extra check to something when it's absolutely not needed? Just wasting cycles...

I do agree, though, that sometimes the more verbose syntax makes things more readable (which is ultimately more important as long as performance is acceptable) in situations where variables are poorly named.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct.

You probably have some coding standard in your company - just see to follow it through. If you don't have - you should :)

Comment: A coding standard that legislates stuff like this is an "organizational smell"

Comment: Coding standards with this level of micro-management annoy me.

Comment: @Steve Townsend: On the other hand, ten different coding styles in one file is a "(dis)organizational stench" and hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is "more correct".  My personal preference is for the more concise form but either is fine.  To me, life is too short to even think about arguing the toss over stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

i personally would prefer

```
if(true == foo)
{
}
```

there is no chance for the ==/= mistype and i find it more expressive in terms of foo's type.
But it is a very subjective question.

Comment: But this is C# and `if (foo = true)` will generate a compile time error.

Comment: @ChrisF: No it won't. The result of "foo = true" is still a bool, so it's fine for the "if" condition. It *does* generate a warning in the MS compiler, however.

Comment: Why stop here when you could do "if (true == (true == (true == foo)))"? Wouldn't this be much more expressive? ;)

Comment: You are right and i love that feature, it's just a personal preference for me coming from c.

Comment: @MrDosu: I'm strongly in favour of abandoning habits from other languages if they don't have any real justification in your new language.

Comment: Well what would justify one over another really? (true == foo or foo == true). One far out example in favor of using == i could think of would be refactoring foo to some other class while overriding the == operator to allow bool comparison without breaking existing code.

Comment: @MrDosu: I believe most people find `(variable == constant)` comparisons easier to read. The only reason to switch it round is to avoid accidental assignment - which is *usually* an error in C# anyway, and is still a warning in this case... although as per my answer, I prefer to do away with the explicit comparison completely.

Comment: @Jon SKeet: Isn't it lovely to be a programmer and have strong feelings about the order of commutative operators :D

Comment: @MrDosu: Commutativity says nothing about readability, which is very important to me.

Comment: @Jon SKeet: I totally agree. Readability is one of the most important aspects in coding nowadays. And most people would do the variable == constant thing. There just isn't any critical difference besides habit.

Comment: @MrDosu: I'd say that natural language is more than just habit... or at least, it's a habit which is so deeply ingrained as to be effectively impossible to change. Whereas habits from another programming language can *definitely* be kicked. So use the most readable form, which is the one most people find most logical according to natural language. That *is* a critical difference IMO.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Well for me it is very logical to think of the value of a variable as more important then the variable itself which leads me naturally to the form I (subjectively) posted here. It also is the form used as coding standard in my development team (favored by most, but definatly not all) so I wouldn't think of it as a personal habit. It is very important to use the one style you choose consistently though or i would agree it would impede readability.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - type in haste, repent at leisure. Yes, it's a warning not an error. I should know by now. (Though if you have warnings as errors set...)