# Something special about true==?

Tags: c#, syntax

I currently have to do some holiday replacement for a collegue and have to change a bit of his code.

I found a lot of conditions like

```
if (true == variablename) {...}
```

I just wonder if there is something special about this syntax? Like most of us I would just write

```
if (variablename) {...}
```

instead. What irritates me is the true at the left side of the condition. Would it be on the right side I would just expect the collegue is not advanced in boolean conditions.

Is there any performance difference or something like that by putting true at the beginning?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if boolean is true?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685002/check-if-boolean-is-true)

Comment: No. Absolutely not. This is mainly about the "true" standing on the LEFT side.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is likely a leftover from learning C/C++, where it was typical to be bitten by this bug:

```
if (variablename = true) { ... }
```

Before compilers was adjusted to warn about this (notice that it does an assignment, not a comparison), the above code was silently executing with a bug.

However, if you learned to write the expression the other way around, you would not get bitten by the above code because it would not compile in this form:

```
if (true = variablename) { ... }
```

In C#, however, it is not a problem, you can write it like you showed without the comparison (as long as it is comparing to `true` anyway), or put the literal on the right side of the comparison operator.

Comment: The C++ - argument seems legit. He started coding a long time ago, I believe :)

Answer (score 4):

No there is no any difference, it's just a code style. That is.

The only thing that come to my mind is:

if `variablename` becomes [Nullable type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1t3y8s4s.aspx) (due some refactoring, typing error or whatever else), this code will still compile and work as expected.

Instead if you write like:

```
if (variablename) {...}
```

you will get compile time error, so you will be *forced to change* the code.

Comment: Thanks. That might be a point, I did not think of, but it should not be affected if true is left or right, correct?

Comment: @OleAlbers: no, there is no any difference.

Answer (score 2):

*Is there any performance difference or something like that by putting true at the beginning?*

I think having the true at the beginning is common for many people with say C++ backgrounds; where it would be easy to allocate a value by putting `if(b = true)` instead of `if(b==true)` ; whereas you couldn't do the same with `if(true = b)`