# do-while loop freezing program

Tags: c#, loops, calculator, do-while

I try using the do-while loop but it doesn't do anything after I enter the input and initiate the button click event. It is supposed to calculate out the amount and list for all the years following until it is <=40,000. I can get the program to run without the loop but not with it.

```
    private double InterestEarned(double AMT, double AIR = 0.07)
    {                        
        return AMT * AIR;
    }

    private double InheritanceAmount(double BAL, double IR, double AIR = 0.07)
    {            
        return (BAL * IR * AIR) - 40000;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            double AMT;
            AMT = (double.Parse(textBox1.Text));

            if (radioButton1.Checked==true)
            {
                do
                {
                const double IR3 = 0.03;
                double BAL, IR, earn;
                int year = 2014;

                AMT = (double.Parse(textBox1.Text));
                IR = IR3;
                year++;
                BAL = InheritanceAmount(AMT, IR);
                earn = InterestEarned(AMT);

                listBox1.Items.Add("You have chosen a 3% inflation rate. Your investment starts at" + AMT.ToString("C") + " and earn 7% a year. You withdraw  $40,000 a year.");
                listBox1.Items.Add("Year" + "\t" + "Interest Earned" + "\t" + "Balance");
                listBox1.Items.Add(year++ + "\t" + earn.ToString("C") + "\t" + BAL.ToString("C"));
                } while (AMT > 40000);
            }
                else if (radioButton2.Checked==true)
                {
                    do
                    {
                    const double IR4 = 0.04;
                    double BAL, IR, earn;
                    int year = 2014;

                    AMT = (double.Parse(textBox1.Text));
                    IR = IR4;
                    year++;
                    BAL = InheritanceAmount(AMT, IR);
                    earn = InterestEarned(AMT);

                    listBox1.Items.Add("You have chosen a 4% inflation rate. Your investment starts at" + AMT.ToString("C") + " and earn 7% a year. You withdraw  $40,000 a year.");
                    listBox1.Items.Add("Year" + "\t" + "Interest Earned" + "\t" + "Balance");
                    listBox1.Items.Add(year++ + "\t" + earn.ToString("C") + "\t" + BAL.ToString("C"));
                    } while (AMT > 40000);
                }
            else
            {                   
                MessageBox.Show("Please select an inflation rate.");                    
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Does stepping through the code in the debugger yield any insights?

Comment: As an aside, the loop duplication can be avoided by taking it out of the `if` block

Comment: Also, since the `Checked` property of a `RadioButton` is a Boolean, I would [do away with the explicit comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3685018/1378739).

Comment: that means I can write it as    if (radioButton1.Checked)

Answer (score 2):

The do...while loop is conditional on the value of AMT being greater than 40000. But the value of AMT only comes from the user (via the textbox) and is never changed again. So the loop just happens forever (which, since it is being run on your UI thread, will lock the UI). Either your condition is wrong or you need to be changing the value of AMT within the loop.

Comment: Yeah it is supposed to be reducing with each loop and stepping through the debugger I can see it is looping, just not correctly. I guess my methods aren't set up right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your while condition is based on the `AMT` variable (> 40000).  You initialize that variable correctly before the do while.  However, you also reinitialize that variable inside the do  while loop and this is why the variable never reach the condition that would make it exit the your do while loop.

The first thing to do here is to comment the line where the AMT variable is set back to it's original value:

```
do
{
  const double IR3 = 0.03;
  double BAL, IR, earn;
  int year = 2014;

  //Comment the line below
  //AMT = (double.Parse(textBox1.Text));
  IR = IR3;
  year++;
  BAL = InheritanceAmount(AMT, IR);
  earn = InterestEarned(AMT);

  //...

} while (AMT > 40000);
```

The next thing you should do is to increase the AMT based on the `earn` value:

```
AMT += earn;
```

The last thing you should consider is way to avoid infinite loop when the AMT original value is <= 0 or when the interest are set to 0.

Comment: When is AMT ever changed? This answer is incomplete. He has an infinite loop even with your change.

Comment: that line is in both loops

Comment: @dman 2306.  Hmm you're right.  I assumed InheritanceAmount and InterestEarned was increasing AMT value, but it ain't

Comment: I messed up and need to use the BAL value instead of AMT. AMT is the intial user input and the BAL is what I need to be reducing and testing.

Comment: Then you have to take the initialization of the BAL value outside of the loop because it won't increase between each iteration.