# C# List Group By with where

Tags: c#, group-by

Hi I'm trying to group by my C# list.
This is how it looks.

```
Name    User    
Fred    true    
Fred    false   
Fred    true    
Joe     true    
Joe     true    
Max     false   
Max     true
```

Result:

[image]

This is how i wanted to look like after Group By, how can i do this in C#?

Comment: Have you tried *anything* yet? You could, for example, just group by name, and then count the "true" values and "false" values separately.

Answer (score 6):

You can group by name and then use [`Enumerable.Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.100).aspx) with a predicate like here:

```
var result = list
   .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
   .Select(g => new 
   { 
       Name = g.Key, 
       True = g.Count(x => x.User == true),
       False = g.Count(x => x.User == false)
   });
```

Comment: don't do their homework, let them do something by themselves first

Comment: x => x.User == true should be x => x.User
    x => x.User == false should be x => !x.User

Comment: @GrayKing: what's the benefit? In this case i prefer `==true` and `==false` because it's easier to read and also corresponds to the property name. It's also clearer that i've presumed that `User` is a `bool` property which OP hasn't mentioned.

Comment: More performant code, and improved readability.  There's no need to compare whether a boolean is equal to true or false, it already is.

true == true is the same as true,
false == true is the same as false.

Comment: @GrayKing: Performance is the same and it's also not more readable (in this case). Maybe it would if the property name would be `IsUser`. Having said that, i also prefer the short version in most cases, but just because i use more meaningful variable/property names. [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685002/check-if-boolean-is-true)