# C# if statement conventions

Tags: c#

Is it better to do something like

```
if (condition == true) {
    //
}
```

or

```
if (condition != false) {
    //
}
```

It's a stupid question, I know, but is there some sort of convention to be followed? Or does either one work based on personal preference? Is one (slightly) faster than the other, and why? Thanks.

Comment: Better: just `if( condition )`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if boolean is true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685002/check-if-boolean-is-true)

Comment: It massively depends on the end result of code readability. If the boolean being tested is "positive sounding" it is usually reads better to just use it alone, or in combination with `!`: `if(enabled)`, `if(!enabled)`. If the boolean being tested is negative sounding it might be better to compare it with a boolean in the negative. `if(disabled)` vs `if(disabled == false)`. Mostly try and name your booleans positive sounding, as it helps avoid "double negatives" in code, which are a bit politician vague - "it's not unattractive" - but that doesn't mean it's attractive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go:

```
if (condition == true) {
    //
}
```

Reads a lot better compared to "if this condition is not false".

You can also go:

```
if (condition) {
    //
}
```

Where condition is type boolean, it will read "if true"

Comment: Side note: `if (codition == true) { ... }` is useful when `condition` is of type `bool?` (*nullable* `bool`). In this case `(codition == true)` means "when `condition` is `true`, not `false` or `null`"